# Is there a SQL Server Management Studio option controlling parameters assignment?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am not able to execute a lot of T-SQL statements due to various errors. The statements are basically some `CREATE OR ALTER` statements of routines. I guess I have turned on/off option of SQL Server Management Studio to force these errors because everything was working OK earlier.

For example the following code:

```
DECLARE @TEST1 DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @TEST2 BIT;
```

gives this:

[image]

If I execute only one of the lines or the following:

```
DECLARE @TEST1 DATETIME2 
SET @TEST1 = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @TET2 BIT;
```

everything is OK.

This cannot be due to SQL Server version/setting or hardware, because the query is working fine on other laptop.

I was using `SSMS 18.0`, then updated to `SSMS 18.1` and nothing change.

Has anyone idea what is causing this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other hidden characters on the machine where this fails. I don't see how you would get that error from the code posted.

Comment: @SeanLange If you mean hidden like ASCII unit separator for example - I am sure there are no such. I have copy the `.sql` files to other machine and execute it without changing anything. Anyway, I guess I will try to find this in the hard way.

Comment: can't reproduce this (not that I thought I could), but I've tested on 3 different environments, just to be sure.

Comment: Have to agree, I can't replicate this on SSMS 18.1 either, and I made sure I copy and pasted the SQL you had, rather than transcribing it, just *incase* there was something off. I note as well that the error specifically states the error is on line 3, which according to your image, is blank.

Comment: What happens if you highlight only the two lines in your screenshot and execute?

Comment: Larnu - strange, yes. Tab Alleman - same error. OK, guys give me some time to examine the options.

Comment: Is there more SQL below that, Perhaps you have some dynamic SQL that is generating the error. SQL run in a dynamic statement has its own lines numbers. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fbd090b429bc2c07cf741aa7610ccf47) for example says the error is on line "3", but that's line 3 of the dynamic statement, the actual error is on line 6 of the whole statement (which tries to assign the value of `@TEST1` to the variable `@t`; which I declared as a `bit`). The error being on line 3 of the whole statement makes no sense, as (like your statement) it is blank.

Comment: Yeah this is a weird one. Please comment back if you figure out what was causing this. I am curious.

Comment: @gotqn so if you highlight those *2* lines and execute the highlighted SQL it says the error is on line 3? That seems very unlikely, as Line 3 wasn't reached.

Comment: Works fine on my machine as well. As per @Larnu, try highlighting only the script you shared in your question and execute?

Comment: The only time I know of that SSMS will mess with the command you input is if you've configured it to use (and respect) Always Encrypted, where it will attempt to transparently translate statements using literals into parameterized ones with encryption, but that should still not have any effect on the code shown here. As an "out of the box" thing, try saving your commands to a new file, verifying that it looks like what you expect, then re-opening that to make sure the editor isn't lying to you.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, man. That was the issue indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was caused by this option:

[image]

We are not using always encrypted, so I guess I have turned it on with some short-key or other way (damn me). If you enable this, open new query window and paste the code above, you will be able to reproduce the issue.

There might be something with how `Parameterization` is working with SSMS when this is ON because some of the statements are not [support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/).